# Spock: method not recognized as an invocation

Tags: groovy, spock

Trying to figure out why Spock doesn't seem to recognize a method call (of a Mocked object) as an invocation. Looked at the docs (http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html#_mocking) and couldn't figure it out.

Here's a dumbed down version of the code:

```
class VmExportTaskSplitter implements TaskSplitter<Export> {

    @Inject
    AssetServiceClient assetServiceClient

    @Override
    int splitAndSend(Export export) {

        Map batch = [:]
        Map tags = [:]

        if (true) {
            println('test')
            batch = assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch(export.containerUuid,
                    export.userUuid, (String) batch.scrollId, tags)
            print('batch: ')
            println(batch)
        }

        return 1

    }
}
```

And now the test:

```
class VmExportTaskSplitterSpecification extends Specification{
    def "tags should be parsed correctly"(){
        setup:
        Export export = new Export(containerUuid: "000", userUuid: "000", chunkSize: 10)
        AssetServiceClient client = Mock(AssetServiceClientImpl)
        VmExportTaskSplitter splitter = new VmExportTaskSplitter()
        splitter.assetServiceClient = client
        Map map1 = [assetIds:["1","2","3","4","5"],scrollId:null]
        client.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String,_ as String, null, _ as Map) >> map1

        when:
        splitter.splitAndSend(export)

        then:
        1 * client.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _ as String, _ as Map)
    }
}
```

Here's the annoying part: both lines on either side of the `assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch` call are printed. But Spock is claiming there are no invocations whatsoever...

```
Using logging directory: './logs'
Using log file prefix: ''
test
batch: [assetIds:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], scrollId:null]

Too few invocations for:

1 * client.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _ as String, _ as Map)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
1 * client.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _ as String, _ as Map)   (0 invocations)
```

... on:

```
1 * client.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _, _ as Map)
```

In `VmExportTaskSplitter` you pass empty `Map` into `getAssetIdBatch` method so `batch.scrollId` will be `null` and it will not match the `_ as String`.

---

Your specification can be also simplified, but it depends on what do you need to test. Guessing from the `then` part you test only if the `getAssetIdBatch` method was called then it is enough to write it like this:

```
def "tags should be parsed correctly"() {
    setup:
    Export export = new Export(containerUuid: "000", userUuid: "000", chunkSize: 10)
    AssetServiceClient client = Mock(AssetServiceClient)
    VmExportTaskSplitter splitter = new VmExportTaskSplitter()
    splitter.assetServiceClient = client

    when:
    splitter.splitAndSend(export)

    then:
    1 * client.getAssetIdBatch('000', '000', null, [:])
}
```

Comment: thanks very much! that answers what I was trying to ask here. Unfortunately, the real code isn't totally fixed with this, if you don't mind could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267791/spock-mocked-classs-method-is-not-being-matched