# Spock: mocked class's method is not being matched

Tags: groovy, spock

I was able to get a passing test for the dumbed down version of my code (thanks to cgrim! [Spock: method not recognized as an invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254616/spock-method-not-recognized-as-an-invocation)), but with the real code it won't work unless the `getAssetIdBatch` returns something that is non-null. I can't figure out why my interactions aren't being implemented. Below, you can see three attempts to get `getAssetIdBatch` to return the `map1` sample.

Here's a dumbed down version of the code:

```
class VmExportTaskSplitter implements TaskSplitter<Export> {

    @Inject
    AssetServiceClient assetServiceClient

    @Override
    int splitAndSend(Export export) {

        Map batch = [:]
        Map tags = [:]

        if (true) {
            println('test')
            batch = assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch(export.containerUuid,
                    export.userUuid, (String) batch.scrollId, tags)
            print('batch: ')
            println(batch)
        }

        return 1

    }
}
```

And now the test:

```
class VmExportTaskSplitterSpecification extends Specification{
    def "tags should be parsed correctly"(){
        setup:
        Export export = new Export(containerUuid: "000", userUuid: "000", chunkSize: 10)
        FilterSet filterSet = new FilterSet()
        filterSet.tag = [:]
        filterSet.tag['tag.Location'] = 'Boston'
        filterSet.tag['tag.Color'] = 'red'
        Map<String, String> expectedTags = ['tag.Location':'Boston', 'tag.Color':'red']
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        export.filters = mapper.writeValueAsString(filterSet)

        def assetServiceClient = Mock(AssetServiceClientImpl) {
            Map map1 = [assetIds:["1","2","3","4","5"],scrollId:null]
            getAssetIdBatch(_ as String,_ as String, null, _ as Map) >> map1
            getAssetIdBatch('000', '000', null, ['tag.Location':'Boston', 'tag.Color':'red']) >> map1
            getAssetIdBatch(_, _, _, _) >> map1
        }

        VmExportTaskSplitter splitter = new VmExportTaskSplitter()
        splitter.assetServiceClient = assetServiceClient

        when:
        splitter.splitAndSend(export)

        then:
        1 * assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _, _ as Map)
    }
}
```

When this is run it can be seen that batch is still being printed as `null`. What am I doing wrong with setting up the interactions?

```
Using logging directory: './logs'
Using log file prefix: ''
test
batch: null
```

Comment: I was able to get it working with the help of this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841668/spock-mock-returns-wrong-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You –like so many before– ran into the one giant gotcha of Spock: the [combination of Mocking and Stubbing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) and the fact that it has to happen in one line. Form the docs:

> Mocking and stubbing of the same method call has to happen in the same interaction.

You stubbed `assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch` to return `map1` in your `given` block and then you verified the mocked call in your `then` block. The latter one implicitly instructs the mock to return `null` instead of `map1`. Think

```
1 * assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _, _ as Map) // >> null
```

Change that line to

```
1 * assetServiceClient.getAssetIdBatch(_ as String, _ as String, _, _ as Map) >> map1
```

and define `map1` in the method's scope and it will work as expected.

You probably want to remove the duplicate from the `given` block as well.

Don't worry about this being in the `then` block. Spock executes all mocking and stubbing before you enter the `when` block. Step through the code if you'd like to see it.